# Fading in a UIView shadow while resizing

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, quartz-graphics

I am attempting to scale my `UIView` at the same time as I fade in a shadow, using the following:

```
    myController.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
    myController.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    myController.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0;
    myController.view.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:myController.view.bounds].CGPath;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
                         //shrink the view
                         myController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8);

                         //fade in the shadow
                         myController.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                          ...etc
```

The view resizes correctly but the shadow appears immediately instead of fading in.

Am I doing something wrong? I thought the `shadowOpacity` was animatable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Core Animations to animate a views layer property:

```
#import <QuartzCore/CAAnimation.h>

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowOpacity"];
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8];
animation.duration = 1.0;
[myView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"shadowOpacity"];
myView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0;
```

Comment: What is the "anim" parameter you are sending to addAnimation: ? Also, is the last line part of triggering the animation, or does it just remove the shadow after it has been animated on?

Comment: @Ryan sorry, typo, fixed it.